# set a field in hibernate to encrypt using sha1 using annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, sha, hibernate-annotations

I have a field in my table that I want to save it using sha1 function in database;
How can I configure hibernate with annotation to use sha1 to save the password field when I call

`session.save(User);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such annotation for Hibernate. If you are using JPA you can define a @PrePersist method to compute the SHA-1 password prior to saving the user object. If you are using regular Hibernate you can do the same with an entity listener.

I would recommend though, that you explicitly handle the hashing of the password in your code, so that it's always clear when it's being done, and how. It's also possible to push the hashing function all the way down to the DB, but of all the options that is probably the least preferred.

Don't forget to salt your password before hashing it!